# Sending Email in Outlook + attached code-file(javascript/AJAX and html content)

Tags: javascript, ajax, outlook

I just want to figure out a strange problem and i wasnt able to find a proper answer so far, so maybe someone here can teach me why the following happens:

The idea is quiet easy. I want to send an email to a friend with an attached code-file. This code-file is a simple .html file with some AJAX/javascript and html content. When my friend opens the file, the script part seems to be deleted during transmission of the email. There is no error, warning or any alert on both sides (sender/receiver). Is it about Outlook? Does it checks the file for forbidden scripts/code and deletes some of the content intelligent by itself? Might it be a problem about using VPN based network?
I hardly have no clue what really happens in this case. I can just imagine that it is a security barrier that handles this modifying, but i cant find anything in the properties of Outlook or the vpn settings.

I´d appreciate if someone could help me to understand this mechanism.

Greetings,
Ohemgi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be [Exchange filtering out your script file](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124399.aspx). You could try renaming the JS file or packaging it into a container type (zip, rar, etc.).

Comment: yeah i know how to solve it. its more about the understanding, why and how files are modified, but the link seems to answer it. Thanks!

Comment: @OhemgiIstalLes Glad it helped you! Please mark this as your answer so others may benefit.

Comment: I just want to point out that the html part is delivered completely. Its just about the content between <script> ... </script> that is deleted. There is no complete file lost, and that is what is very strange in my opinion. The first time i hear about filtering single lines IN a file, but delivering the rest without some kind of alert.

Comment: This is the first I've heard of stripping out embedded HTML content - which version of Exchange are you and your friend using? Did you try sending it to another email address outside your friends domain (gmail, etc.) to see if it's your mail server or your friends?

Comment: Actually the only thing we did, is to change from outlook to gmail, what worked. Thats the reason why im confused about it. Filtering special text/code in a file is pretty unusual isnt it? The Version should be one out of the 2007 series.